# Looking for SQL query for a user chat

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a user chat and i haven't found the right SQL query to get all
messages column, get all member column who send and all member column who receive only with the user x and user y.

I don't want to create row like : receiving_mem_id and sending_mem_id in message because there is another type of chat with some users in a "room".

Here is my database:
[image]

Can you give me some help?

Here is the query I've tried using:

```
Select  me.mem_id
      , me.mem_nickname
      , me.isConnected
      , me.isBreeder
      , m.mess_id
      , m.mess_text
      , m.mess_date
From    PSU.Member As me
      , message As m
      , send As s
Where   me.mem_id = s.mem_id
        And s.mess_id = m.mess_id
        And s.mess_id In (Select    re.mess_id
                          From      message As m
                                  , PSU.Member As me
                                  , receive As re
                          Where     m.mess_id = re.mess_id
                                    And re.mem_id = (Select mem_id
                                                     From   PSU.Member
                                                     Where  mem_id = :mem_id
                                                    ));
```

But the problem I'm having is that any member can see messages sent to the target member.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want (what is your desired output) and what you already tried?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: According to your comment, I modified the query. If you need to filter sent messages on some field from `member` table, add a join and filter data.

```
select me.mem_id
  , me.mem_nickname
  , me.isConnected
  , me.isBreeder
  , m.mess_id
  , m.mess_text
  , m.mess_date
from member me 
join receive r on me.mem_id = r.mem_id
join message m on r.mess_id = m.mess_id
where me.mem_id = :mem_id
and m.mess_id in (
    select mess_id 
    from send s
    where mem_id = :another_mem_id
)
order by m.mess_date desc
```

Comment: Almost!
Here i get all message from :mess_id. Need a filter to get all message sended to :mem_id from another mem_id

Comment: yeah this is good ! problem : i have to do this query twice. One with this query and second by reversing :mem_id with :another_mem_id to display all the chat

Comment: it's ok! i have created one function like ```getReceivedMessage($receiver_id, $sender_id){ }``` to revert easily. Thank you very much @vtuhtan !